# Does Feline Ringworm turn black and crusty when healing?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition

My cat developed ringworm after receiving shots at a Feline Rescue Facility.  The treated area has turned black, and is raised and very crusty ~ is this part of the normal healing process?

Comment: Can you add a picture? Was the ringworm diagnosed by a veterinarian?

Comment: I initially went online to look at feline photos, and the description matched perfectly. The initial round spot (crusty, gray and hairless) showed up near the site where her shot was given, then she subsequently developed a spot on her right foot (the one she uses to rub the area). I began treating her with Raw Vinegar and Coconut Oil (Both have anti-fungal properties), but I will be taking her to a Vet next week and will verify the diagnosis.  In the meantime I thought it strange that the area was turning black, and wondered if it was a sign of healing.

Comment: I don't have that much experience with ringworm, but in the two cases I saw, the skin did not turn black. I would be concerned about this, and get to a vet as soon as possible.

Comment: We confirmed it was ringworm from a Vet ~ she is now being treated.  Thanks.

Comment: My cat has the same issue ,the skin turned black ,did your vet tell you if its part of the healing process?